# Not able to do mouse over operation using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Below is the code

```
WebDriver dr= new ChromeDriver();
dr.get("http://obsessory.com/");
dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
dr.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("username@gmail.com");
dr.findElement(By.name("LoginForm[password]")).sendKeys("password");
dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='signIn']/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/input")).click();
Actions action = new Actions(dr);
WebElement we =  dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a/span"));
action.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a"))).click().build().perform();
```

I wanted to click on 'my accounts' or any of those other links. Kindle tell me how to do that

Comment: Have you created chromedriver using setting system property and chromedriver.exe?

Comment: Ya.. I  have created

Comment: First of all protect your id and password, You have posted credentials into the question. It is bad habit.

Comment: Sorry, I only use Nook.

Comment: @SanjayBhimani. It's OK in this case. The password is so bad, I don't think anyone is going to take it.

Comment: Is the test case working on FireFox()??

Comment: Its working on FireFox so the code is correct only. Just give Thead.sleep(2000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kavya

Please try this code. I think you are not able to type password in password textbox.

For password:

```
dr.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='email'])[2]")).sendKeys("obsessory");
```

For Menu:

```
WebElement we = dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a"));
WebElement ve = dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a"));

Actions act = new Actions(dr);
act.moveToElement(we).click(ve).perform();
```

Hope this will work

Comment: @kavya, Try this and you are trying to click on submenu and for this click( Webelement ) event is present so use this and your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Actions action= new Actions(dr);
WebElement we =  dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a/span"));
action.moveToElement(we).perform();
By locator = By.xpath("html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a");
dr.click(locator);
```

Comment: I have tried this. But i am getting the below exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions

Comment: code is correct just use explicit thread.sleep wait and let me know.